# Twig: how to write if in_array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, twig

I have the following php statement:

```
<?php if(in_array(get_theme_mod('navbar_position'), array('under-header', 'bottom-of-header'))) { ?>
```

I'd like to convert it for use with Twig (I'm using twig to build a wordpress theme), I have found this code snippet but not too sure how to adapt it for what I need:

```
{% if myVar in someOtherArray|keys %}
```

Would it be something like this:

```
{% if theme.theme_mod('navbar_position') in 'under-header', 'bottom-of-header'|keys %}
```

...a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: [How to use in_array() function of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Are you using Timber?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**PHP :**

```
if (in_array(get_theme_mod('navbar_position'), array('under-header', 'bottom-of-header'))) {
```

You don't need to apply the `|keys` filter as you are not testing keys.
The second argument of your function is an array you declare directly in it, with Twig you have to declare it with `[]`.

**Twig :**

```
{% if theme.theme_mod('navbar_position') in ['under-header', 'bottom-of-header'] %}
```

Comment: How about NOT in array?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir use "not in" https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator